# Malloc not allocating as much memory as I tell it to (I believe)

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I want to allocate enough memory for a struct of some size (say, 20 bytes), PLUS an additional number of bytes, say, 500 (this number is calculated at run time and therefore can't simply be an additional field of the struct). So, I have a malloc that looks like this:

```
some_struct *my_struct = (some_struct *) malloc (STRUCT_SIZE + MORE_BYTES);
```

However, I'm fairly certain that malloc is only *really* allocating enough memory for the struct, because that's the kind of pointer I cast the return value to.

If I try to *write* to the memory that *should* have been malloc'd...

```
memcpy(((char *) my_struct) + STRUCT_SIZE, ptr_to_some_data, MORE_BYTES);
```

...and then attempt to *free* that memory, I get the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./my_program: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x09b6d3f0 ***
```

I believe this is because the data that I've copied into the latter part of the heap memory overwrote some information that malloc put at the end of the memory segment, such as size information, or whatever.

Does anyone have insight on this problem? Thanks a lot.

-- Mitchell

EDIT: I found the problem. It was a byte-order issue that I didn't even mention in the original post. Of course, five minutes after I post to Stack Overflow I solve the issue myself! Should I go ahead and delete this post? The problem, as you all have pointed out, was not due to malloc. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: You don't need to cast pointers in C. That's a C++ thing.

Comment: `malloc` has no idea what you're doing with it's return value. That theory is right out.

Comment: Insight: You screwed up somewhere.  `malloc` has no idea what type you'll be casting your allocation to.

Comment: Keep in mind that "my_struct + struct_size" is **indexing** by the length of "my_struct".

Comment: It sounds like it should be pretty trivial to come up with a complete, compilable example that has this problem. Would you mind doing that? There's too much ambiguity in the current description of the problem.

Comment: Use `sizeof(some_struct)` rather than `STRUCT_SIZE`.

Comment: How do you access the extra data once you've copied it?  Are you using a C99 system where you can use flexible array members?

Comment: No: you don't go deleting this post - indeed, you probably can't now there are answers.  You should probably post your solution as an answer and then in a couple of days accept it.  OTOH, the question may end up closed as 'Too Localized'.

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling free() on `(char*) my_struct + STRUCT_SIZE` ?  You can't do that.  free expects the pointer that was returned by malloc, not some offset of the pointer.

You can simply overwrite that data via memcpy - do not free it.  If you want to free it, you will need to free the struct as well.

What you might want to do is add a void* field in your struct and malloc/free that.  Users of the struct will consider it opaque, and you can do whatever it is you need to do in your internal processing.

Comment: I'm calling free on the pointer returned by malloc.

Answer (score 1):

Well malloc allocates the space you request it to allocate. Casting it to the type you want won't tell malloc how much it should allocate. I think your problem is with `memcpy`. Your cast to  `char*` should be like this:

```
memcpy(((char *) my_struct) + STRUCT_SIZE, ptr_to_some_data, MORE_BYTES);
```

Instead of this:

```
memcpy((char *) my_struct + STRUCT_SIZE, ptr_to_some_data, MORE_BYTES);
```

Comment: That actually is how the code is written. I'll fix that in the original post. EDIT to answer a question below: "free(my_struct)"

Comment: Ok, so can you please show the ``free`` call?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to have a struct with a variable length array at the end, like:

```
struct my_struct {
    int some_field;
    char some_data[variable_size];
};
```

You'd do it like this, without the need to do pointer calculation:

```
struct my_struct {
    int some_field;
    char some_data[0];
};

struct my_struct *foo;
foo = malloc(sizeof(struct my_struct) + MORE_BYTES);
memcpy(foo->some_data, ptr_to_some_data, MORE_BYTES);
```

Comment: Lookup 'flexible array members' in C99.  The size of `0` is not allowed in standard C, though GCC may allow it.  The C99 standard allows `char some_data[];` (no size specified; that's a flexible array member).

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware this is a [GCC feature](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_42.html). I have seen it in several projects and done it with `[0]` for years, but you're right, `[]` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What's giving the error, `free(my_struct)`? It shouldn't.

Did you know you can use `foo[]` as the last field of a struct to allow you to access data after then end of the struct?

```
$ cat a.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
   size_t size;
   char   data[];
} packet_t;

int main() {
   const char* some_data = "abc";
   size_t size = strlen(some_data)+1;

   packet_t* packet = (packet_t*)malloc(sizeof(packet_t) + size);
   packet->size = size;
   memcpy(packet->data, some_data, size);

   free(packet);
   return 0;
}
```

Output under `valgrind`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -g -o a a.c && valgrind a
==11153== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11153== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11153== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11153== Command: a
==11153== 
==11153== 
==11153== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11153==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11153==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 8 bytes allocated
==11153== 
==11153== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11153== 
==11153== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11153== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 7)
```